# How can I do to reconcile AGROVOC sparql endpoint with OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine, reconcile

Having this sparql service available http://agrovoc.uniroma2.it/sparql, using the OpenRefine RDF extension, is it possible to use it as a reconciliation service?

So far I've tried but got the following error:

> 12:06:51.461 [..ctReconciliationService] error reconciling 'Lenteja'
> (3153ms) org.shaded.apache.jena.query.QueryException: Endpoint
> returned Content-Type: text/html which is not rcognized for SELECT
> queries

I think may be I got the wrong endpoint.

OpenRefine version is 3.3

Comment: I think that should work. Two possibilities come to mind: 1) the OpenRefine RDF extension isn't correctly setting the Accept headers on its requests or 2) the AgroVoc service is ignoring them. It shouldn't be getting text/html here.

Comment: It might be worth filing a bug report here: https://github.com/stkenny/grefine-rdf-extension/issues

Comment: Can you confirm which version of the RDF Extension you used? v1.2.2 released Sep 30, 2020, fixes error when reconciling against plain SPARQL endpoint.